# Encrypted swap won't mount at boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, encryption, swap, ecryptfs

I need help with my encrypted swap on Ubuntu 14.04. It won't mount.

I used *ecryptfs-setup-swap* to encrypt the swap.

At boot this error occurs:

```
device-mapper: rename ioctl on cryptswap1_unformatted failed: Device  or resource busy.
```

But if I use this command after login it just works without any problems:

Results of `/etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload` :

```
Stopping remaining crypto disks...
cryptswap1 (stopping)...
Starting remaining crypto disks...
cryptswap1 (starting)..
cryptswap1 (started)...
```

These are the entries in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
UUID=479cf731-657a-4f19-bd30-975b4019299f /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

/dev/disk/by-uuid/AAE010E1E010B613 /mnt/AAE010E1E010B613 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show 0 0

/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
```

And this is the entry in the entry in my **/etc/crypttab** file:

```
 cryptswap1 /dev/sda6 /dev/urandom swap,cipher=aes-cbc-essiv:sha256
```

GParted:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to get an error message about setting up the encrypted swap while booting as well, but the encrypted swap was still set up properly.

It seems that may be the case with you, since, when you run `/etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload`, it tells you it's stopping `cryptswap1`, which indicates that it's running.

However, you can verify it. As it says, the device is called `cryptswap1`, so let's see if it's running properly after boot.

### Find out what the actual `cryptswap1` device is

Try booting up and running `ll /dev/mapper/cryptswap1`. It should say the following:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Jul 11 01:52 /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 -> ../dm-0
```

If it says that, it means that `/dev/mapper/cryptswap1` is actually located at `/dev/dm-0`.

### Find out if that device is being used

Run `cat /proc/swaps`. It should give something like the following:

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/dm-0                               partition   4098044 467804  -1
```

If the `Filename` matches the `cryptswap1` device, things are working properly.

Comment: When i boot up and run "cat /proc/swaps" it shows nothing. But when i reload cryptdisks with "/etc/init.d/cryptdisks reload" then it will output this: "/dev/dm-0 partition 8341500 0 -1". It really works like it is supposed to when i reload or restart cryptdisks after the login.

Comment: Okay. /dev/mapper/cryptswap1 is indeed linked to /dev/dm-0. It shuld be set-up correctly, i think.